# Streaming audio from Parse.com – no data retrieved?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, parse-platform, audio-streaming

I am attempting to use Parse.com's data service to stream a set of audio files to an iOS app that I'm developing. Unfortunately, I'm running into a problem retrieving the data using Parse's API – the data that I retrieve, whether I attempt to stream it or not, always has a size of 0 bytes.

I am currently retrieving the PFObject using its ObjectID, retrieving the object audio file as a PFFile, and converting the file to a URL to be loaded into an audio player for streaming. The debugger reveals that the PFFile has a file size of zero bytes, however, and so the URL probably also points to nothing.

Querying Parse using a callback routine:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"StopAudio"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[newStop objectID]
                          target:self
                          selector:@selector(retrieveTourDataCallback:error:)];
```

Using the PFObject produced by the query:

```
PFFile *audioFile = stopAudioObject[@"audioFile"];
NSString *filePath = [audioFile url];
[audioPlayer loadPlayerWith:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
```

The audioPlayer object is a wrapper around an AVPlayer object.

Is there someway that I could stream this data or at least retrieve it from Parse in some other way?

Comment: If you go to the parse browser for your app, can you confirm that the PFFile pointer is attached to your StopAudio class? If so, can you download and confirm it was uploaded correctly?

Comment: I've double checked the Parse data browser for my application and the class does indeed have two entries, both containing audioFile files of type File. These can be successfully downloaded, so it seems like they were uploaded properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I was experiencing has mysteriously disappeared and I'm at a loss for what could have caused it. Although I might have received 0-bytes if there was an issue with the network on the machine that I was running the simulator on, no errors were logged.

But it does work. Another X-File, I suppose.